# Группировка по условию

Tags: python, pandas

Привет есть массив данных.

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12-03-2022 14:57:01 |
| 2 | 12-03-2022 14:57:02 |
| 1 | 12-03-2022 14:57:04 |
| 3 | 12-03-2022 14:58:01 |
| 2 | 12-03-2022 14:59:01 |
| 1 | 12-03-2022 14:59:41 |

Нужно узнать сколько '1','2','3' из столбца column1 при условии что если дата между одинаковыми значениями столбца column1 больше 10 секунд

Результат:

| column1 | count | column2(минимальная из групировки по условию) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 12-03-2022 14:57:01 |
| 2 | 1 | 12-03-2022 14:57:02 |
| 3 | 1 | 12-03-2022 14:58:01 |
| 2 | 1 | 12-03-2022 14:59:01 |
| 1 | 1 | 12-03-2022 14:59:41 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, сделать можно так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("2.csv", parse_dates=[1]) # ваш файл с данными

df['diffs'] = df["column2"].diff().dt.seconds.fillna(0).gt(10).cumsum()
res = pd.DataFrame()

for i, g in df.groupby(["diffs", "column1"]):
    res = res.append({"column1":i[1], "count":len(g), "datetime":g["column2"]
                      .iloc[0]}, ignore_index=True).astype(int, errors="ignore")
```

получаем res:

```
   column1  count            datetime
0        1      2 2022-12-03 14:57:01
1        2      1 2022-12-03 14:57:02
2        3      1 2022-12-03 14:58:01
3        2      1 2022-12-03 14:59:01
4        1      1 2022-12-03 14:59:41
```

Довольно неуклюже, но ничего лучше на ум не приходит пока.

Comment: в формате:

|column1|количество(по условию)|Column2(минимальное значение из групировки по условию|

Comment: Все равно не понятно. добавьте в свой вопрос желаемый результат в его окончательном виде.

Comment: добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: я обновил ответ.